# Show hash for bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to have links for bootstrap modal, for user which want to share this modal, for open modal I use this `$(window.location.hash).modal('show')` but how can I add modal id with hash to url as parameter e.g. `http://test.com/#myModal`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe instead of adding # in the url try checking if it exsists in the window.location.hash and prepend '#' if it's not there?